# get file location when open app from share menu

Tags: android

i use below code to register my application in `audio files` share menu :

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

how can get file name in my activity ?

i tested below code, but not working :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String action = intent.getAction();

    String FilePath  = "";

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action)) {   
        if (extras.containsKey(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) {
            Uri uri = (Uri) extras.getParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
            FilePath = parseUriToFilename(uri);
        }
    }
}

public String parseUriToFilename(Uri uri) {
    String selectedFile = null;
    String filemanagerPath = uri.getPath();

    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        selectedFile = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    if (selectedFile != null) {
        return selectedFile;
    }
    else if (filemanagerPath != null) {
        return filemanagerPath;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? What about your code isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

> how can get file name in my activity ?

Call `getIntent()` to get the `Intent` that started your activity, then call `getData()` on the `Intent` to get the `Uri` of the content to be opened.